# Limpar DataGridView sem disparar evento CellValidating

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando limpar uma DataGridView do C#. Porém ao executar `Rows.Clear()`, antes disso ele está executando um evento `CellValidating` que também esta anexado na DataGridView

Tem como não executar a validação antes de limpar os registros?

Comment: Provavelmente é impossível fazer com que o evento não seja disparado. Se o evento traz algum efeito colateral na hora executar o `Clear` pode ser um bom sinal de que estás a utilizar o evento errado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode sempre criar uma variável de controlo, que fica a `true` antes de fazer o `Rows.Clear()` e passa a `false` imediatamente depois:

```
private bool isClearing = false;

// ...

isClearing = true;
Rows.Clear();
isClearing = false;

// ...

private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if(isClearing)
    {
        // return ou simplesmente e.Cancel = true;
        // dependendo das necessidades
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Otimo, Joao. nao tinha pensando nisso  haha, funcionou perfeitamente, abraco

Comment: Ainda bem que pude ajudar! Aproveite e marque a resposta como correta ;).